# BlackBerry wifi implementation failure

Tags: blackberry, wifi

I have problems with wifi connection in application. Everything worked fine with ";deviceside=true"  but  using ";interface=wifi"  caused problems, and gives me "Tunnel Failed" exception, what is wrong?  (tested in Bold 9000 real device)

Comment: Are you definitely connected? Can you turn off mobilenet, and connect to internet via a 3rd party app that does explicit wifi? The 9000's wifi is brutally bad. Even if it shows the name of a network, you might not be connected. Check that you have a green check in the connection manager screen. If you have a white dash it will never work even if it shows the name of the network (as if you're connected).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing any code, but try using [Versatile Monkey's Network Helper class](http://www.versatilemonkey.com/blog/index.php/2009/06/24/networking-helper-class/) for your connections, it supports Wi-Fi and all the other BlackBerry connection permutations quite seamlessly.